# Send Background location Parameter(Latitude and Longitude) to server in ionic(Cordova)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to cordova-ionic app development. I need to send the location parameters (latitude and longitude) continuously to the server using web service. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Geolocation (latitude, longitude, .. ) in Cordova from the following [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation)

Once you setup and successfully run this plugin, use javascript [interval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to fetch location every minute or hour etc

```
setInterval(function(){ 
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}, 3000);
```

3000  = 3 secs